# .NET Memory Leak, Use the GC.Collet() or Don't

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I have the following code with vb.net:

```
Public Async Function WriteData(buffer() As Byte, offset As Integer, count As Integer) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
        Try
            Using data_writer = IO.WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsStreamForWrite(_outputStream)
                Await data_writer.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count)
                Await data_writer.FlushAsync
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
             Logger.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I call the function WriteDate too much, but I notice an increase in memory every time I call the function, as you can see the datawriter stream and the _outputStream are disposed because the usage of Using.

When I run the vs Profiler, the profiler shows me that 95% of memory are excessive reserved by the byte array which is "buffer" in my code.

1- Do you see any problem in my code?
2- How Can I clear the byte array?

-- I added the following code to that function after the line Await data_writer.FlushAsync

```
buffer = Nothing
GC.Collect()
```

So my memory doesn't increase as before, but I call WriteData too much in my app, and I read that it is not recommended to call GC.Collect too much.

Without calling GC.Collect the memory jumps to 300 MB, with GC.Collect() memory does not exceed 50MB.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generic GC problem, not specific to Phone or Await.  Although it certainly doesn't help to solve the problem.  The issue is that your buffer is too large, more than 85KB.  Too large to be easily compacted by the GC so it gets allocated in the Large Object Heap.  Now there are not enough small objects anymore in generation 0 to trigger a collection.  The LOH only gets cleaned during a gen#2 collection, so calling GC.Collect() is indeed a workaround.

Two basic strategies to avoid having to call Collect().  First strongly favor using a smaller buffer, small enough to get allocated in gen#0.  Doing little bits of work is always better, the Await keyword should really help to make that a trivial change in your code.  Hard to tell, we can't see the caller.

Second strategy is to *reuse* the buffer so you only ever need one of them.  How easy that is again depends strongly on what the caller looks like.

Comment: Many Thanks @Hans, really a promesing solution. 1- Split the buffer less then 85K may decrease the performance and speed 2- how can i REUSE the buffer?

Comment: No, there's no scenario where I/O is ever going to noticeably slow down due to small buffers.  Not unless you make the buffer smaller than a kilobyte.  Watch out for premature optimization, especially on a phone.  A good buffer size is 4096 bytes.  I can't help you figure out how to reuse the buffer, I can't see the code that calls this method.

Comment: Many thanks @Hans your answer is fair enough , thanks for your time.

Comment: btw, I will try to adjust the buffer size, if not, will try to call the GC when memory exceeded the 100 MB not every call for the function.

Answer (score 3):

You should understand the way the GC works before you try to control it.  A garbage collection is driven primarily by "memory pressure;" that is, when your program is short of memory for immediate use, a collection will occur in order to release some.

The reason that your memory use is 300MB without calling `GC.Collect` is because .NET isn't under pressure when running your code.  Because it's not under pressure, it doesn't waste time running a collection.  The 300MB of allocated memory isn't being actively used - your code isn't magically more efficient just because you're calling `Collect` - but there's no reason for .NET to tidy up at that point.

My advice would be: don't call `GC.Collect`, unless you have a specific and meaningful reason to reduce the memory use of your application.  When it needs to, the garbage collector will collect that memory itself (you'll likely see your usage grow, and then drop back to ~50MB periodically).

Comment: Thanks, but some time my app closes because the memory reach the 300 MB, working on WP8 project and there is a memory limitation. and even the profiler warns me about the bytes reserved in the memory.

Comment: It might have been useful to mention that in your question... :-)

Comment: I'm so sorry @Dan Puzey forget to mention.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in an other scenario, with HTTP Server, but I found the real solution :

Do never use AsStreamForWrite(), use the WinPRT IOuputStream directly (I guess it's possible, even in VB) 
AsStreamForWrite() creates an internal Stream which just eats the memory (in several case) and never releases it.

Comment: Dear @Poppyto, do you have any proof of problem with AsStreamForWrite, or for it is for your own experience?

Comment: Proof is the experience : I spent 72hour on a big memory leak (a local web server which "proxyfing" files), when I removed AsStreamForWrite and use WinPRT object directly, I had no more memory leak. I know it was not my fault because memory profiler confirmed it was not a .NET memory problem (so a native memory problem!), so forget about GC.Collect and other.